# How can I delete a row after groupby in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following datafram:

```
account_num   trans_cdi
1             c
1             d  
3             d
3             c
3             d
```

It's part of a bigger dataframe. First, I'd like to group the account_num column, and then delete the row inside a group where the group starts with "d" in trans_cdi column. So in this case the new dataframe would look like this:

```
account_num   trans_cdi
1             c
1             d  
3             c
3             d
```

I tried like that, but it deletes the whole group:

```
df = df.groupby("account_numb").filter(lambda x: x["trans_cdi"].iloc[0] != "d")
```

Thanks!

Comment: So are you trying to remove duplicates?

Comment: No, just the first element in a group has to start with "c" and not "d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this to work with `filter` for some reason, so I used `transform` and indexing instead, and it returned the expected utput:

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('account_num')['trans_cdi'].transform(lambda x: (x.iloc[0] != "d") | (x.index != x.index[0]))]


   account_num trans_cdi
0            1         c
1            1         d
3            3         c
4            3         d
```

Would this generalize for what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

You can first get row count per group , then calculate if not(row count equals 0 and row equals d) which takes care of the forst row in each group not equal to d.

```
idx = df.groupby('account_num').cumcount()
out = df[~(idx.eq(0) & df['trans_cdi'].eq('d'))]
```

---

```
print(out)

   account_num trans_cdi
0            1         c
1            1         d
3            3         c
4            3         d
```